# Setting a minimum learning rate on "Reduce On Plateau"

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm currently using PyTorch's `ReduceLROnPlateau` learning rate scheduler using:

```
learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.params, lr = learning_rate)
model.optimizer = optimizer
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(model.optimizer, factor=0.9, patience = 5000, verbose=True)
```

My issue is that the loss will get really low within a few minutes, then jumps really high and start decreasing steadily. Hence, `ReduceLROnPlateau` will just continuously decrease the learning rate to a point that the model can't learn anything (because it takes the lowest loss into acount).

Is there a way to set a minimum learning rate using this scheduler so that it won't go to almost 0? Say to set it at minimum of `1e8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau):

> `min_lr` (`float` or `list`) – A scalar or a list of scalars. A lower bound on the learning rate of all param groups or each group respectively. Default: `0`.

You can simply go for:

```
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    model.optimizer,
    factor=0.9,
    patience=5000,
    verbose=True,
    min_lr=1e-8,
)
```

Comment: Oh awesome! Don't know how I missed that one. Thanks